# Reproducing Hydrogen Molecule Hamiltonian in OpenFermion

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecular-orbital-theory, energy, molecules

I am learning quantum chemistry at the moment and I'm trying to understand the Hamiltonian generated by the [OpenFermion](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=openfermion) package. I'm now stuck at understanding how openfermion calculates the coefficients in second quantization Hamiltonians.

Take the for Hydrogen molecule for example. My understanding is that the coefficients

> - $h_{00}$, represents electron 1 in 1s orbit with spin up.
> - $h_{11}$, represents electron 1 in 1s orbit with spin down.
> - $h_{22}$, represents electron 2 in 1s orbit with spin up.
> - $h_{33}$, represents electron 2 in 1s orbit with spin down.

As the wavefunction of 1s orbits takes the form

$$\psi_{1s}(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}$$

The $h_{ii}$ should be

\begin{equation}
2\pi \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\psi_{1s}(r)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2-2r R\cos\theta}}\right)\psi_{1s}(r)r^2 \sin\theta d\theta dr
= -1.07123
\end{equation}
when $R = 0.74$ Bohr radius, which does not match with openfermion's
\begin{align}
h_{00} &= h_{11} = -1.2524635735648988\\
h_{22} &= h_{33} = -0.47594871522096416
\end{align}

Can anyone tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: Is there spin down in $h_{22}$ ? Is it not spin up ?

Comment: yeah it should be spin up. I just fixed the typo

Comment: Isn't this just basically considering two separate H atoms, not a hydrogen molecule? I'm quite inexperienced in this, but do we not have to consider the attraction of two electrons to both separate nuclei? Also, why is $h_{11}$ not equal to $h_{33}$ as both have the same spin and the assignment of which electron is electron 1 or 2 is arbitrary.